# Can't change nav-bar link's color in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, css-selectors, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change nav bar's one link's color while I tried all ways it still has a default color.
Here is the code:

```
<li class="nav-item signup">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/signup" >Sign Up</a>
      </li>
```

**css**

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link li a.signup {
    color:#ffffff !important;
}
```

I am trying to change sign up buttons link color. An interesting fact is that the background color of nav-item (.signup class) was possible to change while a link is impossible.

How can I change that a link color? What is wrong on the css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your anchor has `.nav-link` class, your `.nav-item` has the custom `.signup` class. Where did you come up the structure of `.nav-link li a.signup`?

Try this:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-item.signup .nav-link {
    color:#fff;
}
```